# Что за оператор?

Tags: javascript

Это знак **!=** не равняется, а что значит **=!** ?

Искал инфу, но так и не нашел ответ.

```js
setInterval(() => main.hidden = !main.hidden, 1000);  //  Что значит =! ???
```

```css
#main{
background: orange; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
TEXT
</div>
```

Comment: это два отдельных оператора: перевод значения выражения в отрицательное с помощью `!`, к примеру - `let t = true; t = !t; console.log(t)` выведет `false`

Comment: =! переводит любое значение в отрицательное значение?
Например с  1==1 будет true, а  1==!1 будет false?

Comment: Это унарный `not`, в `C`-подобных языках он вот такой `!`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых вы ошиблись. Не `=!`, а `= !` (пробел между символами) и разница большая. Первого не существует в принципе. А второй это всего лишь равно и знак отрицания для переменной.

Например

```js
let a = true;
console.log(a); // true 
console.log(!a); // false
```

То есть фактически у вас написано, что значению `x` присвоить значение обратное `x`.
Как правило это применяется для булевых переменных.

Либо для приведения какого-то значения к булеву:

```js
let a = '5';

console.log(!!a);
```

Тут первый `!` приведёт значение в булев тип, но тогда он будет `false`, а чтобы сделать обратно `true` применяется второй `!` для логического отрицания `false` (для коего будет `true`)

Comment: А почему в js без пробела знак =! работает?
= ! это значит перевести число в отрицательное?
если вместо true будет число 2, то со знаком = ! получится  минус 2 (-2) ?

Comment: Работать-то работает. но правильное написание именно с пробелом, где восклицательный знак "прилепляется" к переменной, а не знаку равно. Это как раз для того, чтобы у новичков не возникало вопросов что за знак `=!`  :)  (если попроще выражаясь)    ........... Это не значит "перевести в отрицательное", это  логическое отрицание..... есть логические операторы например AND, OR, NOT, XOR. Вот восклицательный знак выполняет операцию `NOT`. И это для операций с булевыми данным и в 99% случаев. В 1% случае для неявного приведения типа к булевому (см. нижний пример в ответе)

Comment: Но в js насколько я знаю всего два булевых типа это true и false?

Comment: И в js и во всех языках мира значения для булевых true или false (null в расчёт не берём)

Comment: Значит всего 2 булевых значения?

Comment: Да. Правда или Ложь. Других не дано. Как Инь и Ян))